# Excel formula Inquiry Regarding Budget Tracker

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Please note:**  every single option I found online prior to this post were super complicated.

I have decided to create my own budget tracker. I figure this will help me get a better handle on finances than what I've been doing (putting it into OneNote). Here is how I have my sheet setup:

[image]

Here is what I'm looking to do:

1. Sum up the **-** columns if the **Expected** & **Monthly** columns are **Y** or **y** (I can figure the annual once I get this one)
2. sum up the **-** columns who have **Y** or **y** in their **Business** column (should be similar to 1, right?), but use the **% of bill** column as part of it, since some bills (like internet) are not just for business ...

   e.g.:  SUM **Column L (Business)** x (**Column M (% of Bill)** /
   100) where **Column L** is Y or y
3. Sum up all rows in **-** who have **EDU** in **Which fund** column (I can figure out LTSS, GIV, FFA, and FUN from there)
4. Sum all rows in **+** where **Description** is **paycheck**

Comment: You can use `SumIFS`

Comment: Great! I'll try that and see if I have issues. Some of the other calculation formulas I've found weren't very clear on how to use them.

Comment: holy cow that's super easy! All ofthe other things I was looking at were SUPER complicated. @RicardoDiaz - can you please make that an answer so I can give you props?

Comment: You should also check out averageif(), averageifs(), maxifs(), minifs(), countif() and countifs() as they all can be so useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conditionally sum data you can use `SumIFS` function

**From the source:**

Syntax

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

Here is the [official function reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

---

**In your picture:**

Sum_range: Column with values `+` / `-`

Criteria_range1: Column `Monthly`

Criteria: `"Y"`

---

Other [good examples](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function)

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! As mentioned in prior comment, everything I found online was super complicated.

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable, provide the working example in the body of your answer so if, or when, the link fails the answer still has value.

Comment: @SolarMike Absolutely right. Thanks for the heads up. Edited the question.